# Find CB of a traingle

Tags: geometry

There is a circle. Let A, B, C be points on the circle such that chord AC = 20 and chord AB = 24. Angle CAB is acute. Let H is the midpoint on AC such that HK = 8 (K is a point on AB). HK is orthogonal to AB.

Please help me find CB.

Here is my attempt.

From triangle AHK cos(A) = 3/5.

From cos's theorem

CB^2 = 400 + 576 - 2*20*24*(3/5) = 784 => CB = 28.

But actually the answer to the problem is 20.
I cannot understand where I have made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why "From triangle AHK cos(A) = 3/5."?

Comment: Triangle AHK is a right triangle. According to the definition of trigonometric functions, in a right triangle each acute angle's sin = (front leg)/(hypotenuse) and cos = (adjacent leg / hypotenuse).

Comment: "cos = (adjacent leg / hypotenuse)."

adjacent leg =?  hypotenuse=?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Rtriangle.svg  Please look at the picture. cos(A) = b/c. hypotenuse means side c of the pic.

Comment: Triangle AHK is a right triangle. 
 
Why cos(HAK)=3/5?

Comment: @Marie: $\cos\angle{HAK}=AK/HA$. Are you saying that $AK/HA=3/5$?

Comment: I am just saying that  cos∠HAK=AK/HA = 6/10 = 3/5. Right?

Comment: Why is AK/HA=6/10? You have not said anything about AK or about AH. From the information in the question K could be anywhere on the side AB.

Comment: As H is the midpoint of AC => AH=HC = 10 => AK = 6. Right?

Comment: Finally, you give the critical information that H is the midpoint of AC! Now your solution is fine except for your arithmetic. 400 + 576 - 2*20*24*(3/5) = 784 is wrong!

Comment: Come on what a stupid mistake I'd made. Thanks a lot. I was really consuming my whole energy to find my stupid mistake. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\angle AKH$ is right angle, we know that $AK = 6$

We also know that $\frac{AH}{AC} = \frac12$. Let $L$ be another point on $AB$ such that $CL \perp AB$.

Since $\angle AKH$ and $\angle ALC$ are both right angles, clearly $\triangle AKH$ and $\triangle ALC$ are similar. So $\frac{AK}{AL} = \frac{AH}{AC} = \frac12$, and then $AL = 12$.

Then $BL = AB - AL = 12$, $BL = AL$.

So $\triangle ABC$ is a isosceles triangle with $AC = BC$, which gives us $BC = 20$